# File output Node not working

Tags: node-editor

So for whatever reason the File output node doesn't work for me, doesn't matter if i do render image or render animation I've double checked that the output folder actually exists, but nothing happens. Am I missing something obvious?

[image]

Comment: Check the permission on the folder. Also, try using forward slash `/` instead of backslash `\ ` in the folder path ex: `c:/test/`

Comment: @Bruno I've tried both version of slashes, I also tried browsing into the folder using the gui with no luck. as far as I'm aware there is no special permission on this folder and I also tried to change it to a folder that takes the rendering output using the regular way.

Comment: Do you have multiple render layers and this one might not be included?

Comment: @Bruno nope, I had 2 layers but deleted one of them and saw no change

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I figured out what was wrong, the compositing in post processing was disabled so I just had to tick the box to enable it.

[image]

Comment: quote form blender doc:
"Unlike the render output filepath, this node uses a base directory and an image name, by default the output path is composed of: {base path}/{file name}{frame number}.{extension}."