# File Output Node not Working in Certain Cases

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I am aware of this thread: [File output Node not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172723/file-output-node-not-working)

However this is not my problem. I have used this file to output to files, but I am trying to use a 3rd scene in order to composite the 1st 2 scenes and output them individually for further compositing in different software later.

[image: File Outputs not working]

The 2 scenes are compositing and rendering as a png perfectly, but the individual scenes will not save as exr's. I just cannot understand it. This should work.

I've checked everything I can think of. It also will not save the renders with the composited layers disconnected. This setup worked in other setups.

I was delighted to find that you can render scenes with different render engines in the one render pass, and I can even composite them in blender - it's all working, but I want the renders seperated to use in VFX software.

Actually - now I think of it I am using 2.92 beta, I will try the release (2.91) where I had this working before. But I'll leave this here in case anybody else runs across the issue, or in case somebody might know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-exr-image and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22928/different-render-per-layers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: No the problem persisted in 2.91. No file was outputted for each of the renders. Neither of the threads susu pointed to was relevant to this situation, although I did not try using a separate output node for each render layer. I will try this next. I successfully used a single file output node outputting different render passes but possibly it doesn't work when rendering separate layers. In the end, I rendered each layer manually - the Eevee layer rendered extremely quickly so it was not too much of an issue. I would like to resolve this because I'd like to make it part of my work flow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will work when you would use 2 output nodes, one per layer.

Comment: Hi everyone or anyone - I am still having a problem with this. It's a problem when when combing Eevee scene renders and cycles - I really need to get the exr's seperate for compositing. The file output nodes are absolutely not working. Everything is set up correctly, but natch.